# Make Dropdown disappear on click JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I am a newbie and I'm trying to make webapp for iPhone.

I have a dropdown that works well on desktop Chrome, but because there is no mouse, I cannot figure out how to make the dropdown menu disappear once a list choice is made:

```css
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: center;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <h2><span onClick=”return true” >Select Room</span></h2>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="menucontainer">
    <p><a href="#kitchen">Kitchen</a></p>
    <p><a href="#family">Family Room</a></p>
    <p><a href="#diningRoom">Dining Room</a></p>
    <p><a href="#livingRoom">Living Room</a></p>
    <p><a href="#cabana">Cabana</a></p>
    <p><a href="#guesthouse">Guest House</a></p>
    <p><a href="#Patio">Patio</a></p>
    <p><a href="#exterior">Exterior</a></p>
    <p><a href="#laundryRoom">Laundry Room</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added

`onClick=”return true”`

in order to be able to select the menu and get it to drop down on my Safari iPhone

**************** EDIT ****************

Well I don't understand how [this fiddle does exactly what I want](https://jsfiddle.net/bulldoglowell/bbj56q0s/15/) but this webpage does not!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>

$("select-room").click(function(){
        $("#menucontainer").toggle();
        alert("click");
    });

</script>
<style>

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: center;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="dropdown">
  <h2><span class="select-room" onclick="true" >Select Room</span></h2>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="menucontainer">
    <p><a href="#kitchen">Kitchen</a></p>
    <p><a href="#family">Family Room</a></p>
    <p><a href="#diningRoom">Dining Room</a></p>
    <p><a href="#livingRoom">Living Room</a></p>
    <p><a href="#cabana">Cabana</a></p>
    <p><a href="#guesthouse">Guest House</a></p>
    <p><a href="#Patio">Patio</a></p>
    <p><a href="#exterior">Exterior</a></p>
    <p><a href="#laundryRoom">Laundry Room</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if my answer works for u please consider accepting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*update for the new fiddle*

you can use `jquery toggle` (hide/show)  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4bmnjkx/1/)

jquery

```
$(".dropdown").click(function(){
   $("#menucontainer").toggle();
});
```

your markup

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <h2><span onClick=”return true” >Select Room</span></h2>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="menucontainer">
    <p><a href="#kitchen">Kitchen</a></p>
    <p><a href="#family">Family Room</a></p>
    <p><a href="#diningRoom">Dining Room</a></p>
    <p><a href="#livingRoom">Living Room</a></p>
    <p><a href="#cabana">Cabana</a></p>
    <p><a href="#guesthouse">Guest House</a></p>
    <p><a href="#Patio">Patio</a></p>
    <p><a href="#exterior">Exterior</a></p>
    <p><a href="#laundryRoom">Laundry Room</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

your css

```
 .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: center;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    //display: block;
}
```

Comment: I'm at my wits end here!  Can yo kindly refer to the commented OP?

Comment: basically  when you clicked toggle (its mean .select-room class) add `display: none` in the `#menucontainer`, another click then `display: block`.

Comment: Arguvanli  I am uncertain what you mean... Did you try the fiddle above and the HTML I posted in the EDIT?

Comment: check fiddle again

Comment: Yes the fiddle does what I want... the HTML i reposted, does not!

Comment: Well, it doesn't disappear like  [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bulldoglowell/bbj56q0s/15/) above.

Comment: I just changed click event class is this okay now?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the menu when a link on menu is clicked:

```
$('body').on('click','.dropdown a',function(){
      $('.dropdown').hide();
});
```

Comment: I'm not clear on the syntax here...  '.dropdown a' ?  I tried to fiddle this but couldn't get it to work.  The menu stays put on select.

Comment: `.dropdown a` means `a` tags inside element with class `.dropdown`

Answer (score 1):

heres a jquery exmple

```js
$('#id').change(function(){
  $('#id').addClass('hidden');
});
```

`onchange()` is specific to textbox and select elements so its  good practice to use it rather then  click listener

here is a fiddle for method proof

```js
$('#selectElement').change(function(){
  alert("text changed");
});
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select id="selectElement">
  <option value="val1">val1</option>
  <option value="vl2">val2></option>
</select>
```